IBM MQ and IISExpress stopped working after recent update. Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\mqe.dll
After recent Windows updates, any application that uses IISExpress and IBM MQ have stopped working. Applications on IIS are working fine. Any Windows service or WinForms app that uses IBM MQ are also working fine.
When you press F5 in Visual Studio and application starts in IISExpress, when it reaches code line to establish connection to MQ, Visual Studio just stops and you see this entry in event viewer.
Faulting application name: iisexpress.exe, version: 8.5.9748.0, time stamp: 0x5384d451
Faulting module name: mqe.dll, version: 7.500.600.16058, time stamp: 0x56d1088a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x001b8a53
Faulting process id: 0xcc8
Faulting application start time: 0x01da9b80a70e02f6
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\mqe.dll
Report Id: bebc44d8-3037-4711-852b-3be9cba42b1d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 

Any idea what is causing this? Tried both 32 and 64 bit IISExpress and same issue.

What is IBQ MQ?

This is a very old out of date MQ version that the dll is from: Faulting module name: mqe.dll, version: 7.500.600.16058

Are you able to run MQ apps not in IIS? For example, the amqsput or amsqputc sample? I'm wondering whether your MQ install has been broken or whether it is just the link between IIS and the MQ installation that is broken.

Yeah this seems to be some issue in MQ install. Version 7.5 is already installed and on top of that I installed version 9.1. Version 7.5 is primary but IISExpress is not working. Uninstalled version 9.1 and it fixed the issue.

Also IIS Express 8.5 should have reached end of life (like its sibling IIS 8.x). You need to use IIS Express 10 (ideally the latest with VS2022).

Hmmm, I read "Windows Update" as a change to the OS - I did not realise you meant that you had made a change to the MQ installation. For future reference, such things probably should be spelled out more clearly.

If "IBQ MQ" is a typo you should fix it in the question title and the body.

IBQ changed to IBM

@FrankMartin If MQ 7.5 is your primary, then I suspect you have run setmqenv to set the path for MQ 9.1. Assuming so, it might be that you have another environment variable in your wider config pointing to MQ 7.5 libs which is potentially causing an conflict.
